# Application window overflows my screen, can't resize

Tags: 22.04, display, screen

I'm having a problem on **Ubuntu 22.04** with a window overflowing my screen. It happens with some applications only. I have for example **PyCharm** open on my system. Here, the window is outside my screen.

[image: Pycharm open on my system]

[image: Switching to Activities view]

After switching to Activities view, I can see two buttons that are hidden beneath my screen. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please don't add "solved", etc. to the question. Marking your answer as accepted when you are able to is enough to consider the question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after playing around in the settings for hours, I found that I had increased the **IDE UI font size** which was set to `15px`. After setting it to `14px`, everything works as normal!